# Is there a way to select string before a pattern in regex?

Tags: regex

I want to extract `These are words before hashtag` from the below line:

```
* These are words before hashtag  #work/abc/xyz/123
```

I have tried `\#.*`, which highlights everything after `#hashtag`. How can I select words before the hashtag using a single regex statement?

[image]

Comment: Use `.*#` instead.

Comment: What is your expected output? `\w+(?=.*#)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKRO2L/1))? `(.*)#(.*)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKRO2L/2))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a capture group for the chars before the #, and match optional spaces followed by the # after it.

```
^([^#\r\n]+?)[^\S\r\n]*#
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^#\r\n]+?` Match 1+ times (non greedy) any char except `#` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match optional spaces without newlines
- `#` Match literally (Note that you don't have to escape the `\#`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jDvyEF/1)

Or with a lookahead:

```
^[^#\r\n]+?(?=[^\S\r\n]*#)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KN3ioo/1)

Answer (score 3):

```regex
^[^#\r\n]*(?= #)
```

`^` = Begin matching from the start.

`[^#\r\n]+` = Match at least one character, but not hashes or new line characters.

`(?= #)` = Match a space and a hash, but don't capture them.

Examples here: https://regex101.com/r/PDWT39/1